# Expression evaluates to a different number when made a function

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

The following expression evaluates to zero at large `n` when just using replacement, but if the same expression is defined as a function `f[n]`, it suddenly evaluates to a nonzero number. Redefining the function by absorbing the denominator into `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized` again gives a vanishing answer. Applying `N` to all of these gives a nonzero answer. Is this an issue with precision control, and if so, how do I fix it, and which result should I trust?

```
exp = n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, -1]
f[n_] := n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, -1]
f1[n_] := n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, -1]
f1[n] == f[n] // FullSimplify
{exp /. {n -> 256.}, f[256.], f1[256.], N[exp /. {n -> 256}], N[f[256]], N[f1[256]]}
```

Output: `{0., 109.439, 0., 109.439, 109.439, 109.439}`.

Comment: It should be mentioned that your code produces a warning about potential loss of precision (at least for me). Also, `f[n]/.n->256.` gives the same result as using `exp`, so I guess it's an issue with the expression being rewritten when `n` is used instead of a number. Lastly, why not simply use `f[256]` or `N[f[256]]`? - this way, you don't have any issues with machine precision numbers

Comment: @LukasLang yeah I guess I’m trying to understand the difference between all of these things. N[f[n]] seems to be extremely slow, but maybe that’s just a sign of the lack of precision in f[256.]. It looks like f[N[256,700]] actually works better, but I’m not yet sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Well, `N[f[256]]` uses exact numbers with infinite precision, `f[N[256,700]]` uses 700 digits of precision, and `f[256.]` less than 20. This should explain both the speed differences and the difference in the accuarcy of the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

exp = n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, -1];
f[n_] := n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 
   2 + n, -1]
f1[n_] := n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 1 - n, 
   2 + n, -1]
f1[n] == f[n] // FullSimplify

(* True *)

{exp /. {n -> 256.}, f[256.], f1[256.], N[exp /. {n -> 256}], N[f[256]], 
  N[f1[256]]} // Quiet

(* {0., 109.439, 0., 109.439, 109.439, 109.439} *)
```

This is a precision issue with some representations (which alter the sequence of operations). Just avoid machine precision by using arbitrary-precision.

```
exp /. {{n -> 256.}, {n -> 256.0`15}, {n -> SetPrecision[256., 15]}} // Quiet

(* {0., 109.438999105, 109.438999105} *)

f1 /@ {256., 256.0`15, SetPrecision[256., 15]}

(* {0., 109.438999105, 109.438999105} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why the precision appears to be different when `n` is an argument of a function as opposed to replacement.

Comment: @level1807 That's not the issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is fun. Let's make it even more mysterious:

```
Clear[n]
exp = n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 
   2 + n, -1]
"test with Block:"
Block[{n = 256.}, exp]  (* 0, with a warning *)
Block[{n = 256.}, 
 n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, -1]] (* 109.439 *)
```

Use `Trace` to see the divergence in evaluation:

```
Trace@Block[{n = 256.}, exp]
Trace@Block[{n = 256.}, 
  n^2/2 Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2] Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, -1]]
```

Bottom line:
Use the one that does not give a warning. (And btw, you can evaluate the expression in pieces, which supports this.)

```
Clear[n]
expr = {n^2/2, Gamma[n + 1/2]/Gamma[n + 2], Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n, 2 + n, -1]};
Times @@ (expr /. {n -> 256.})
```